# Simultaneous factor solution - Factor analysis

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, factor-analysis

In order to replicate the results of a previous study, I am trying to apply a method of factor analysis of a matrix that is described in [Horst (1965)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkOsv.jpg) as "basic structure with simultaneous factor solution".

How would I approach this method in R?

Given a matrix `m`, and providing for instance that I extract two factors, I have tried applying  the following:

```
fa(r = cor(m), rotate = 'none', factors = 2)
```

but I don't think this approach is right.

Just found out.

```
Library(psych)
Principal(r= cor(m), rotate = " none ", nfactor= 2)
```

Does the job. Horst refers to what is also called an eigen value decomposition. It can also be done using eigen() and attaining the same result.

.. not really.. loadings seem pretty close but looking at the maths I am not sure the method described below is akin to eigen value decomposition in fact, looking more closely, the method is applied directly on the raw data and no product momentum calculations are required..

.. I am trying (slowly) to work out the maths myself and  to understand what the computation instruction describes.

For your information, here is the standardized matrix that is used for the calculation carried out in the example in the original textbook:

```
 0.444  0.627  1.458  1.754  2.967  2.585  0.970  0.616  0.853
 2.648  2.563  1.950 -1.341 -1.015 -0.700  0.904  0.976  0.150
-0.104 -0.159  0.049  0.510 -0.378 -0.468  2.217  2.378  2.291
-0.970 -1.216 -1.129 -0.079 -0.378 -0.645  0.287  0.312 -2.266
-1.164 -1.060 -1.485 -1.878 -0.021 -0.530 -1.483  0.190 -0.429
-0.956 -1.122 -0.938 -1.282 -0.779  0.121  0.447 -1.565 -0.429
 0.198 -0.242 -0.055  0.021  0.526 -1.528 -0.575 -1.244 -0.114
-0.035 -0.485  1.129 -0.014 -0.894 -0.316 -1.421 -0.705 -0.349
-1.050  0.786 -0.048  0.101 -0.354 -0.433 -0.298 -0.377 -0.256
 0.298  0.197 -0.010  0.558  0.253  0.464 -0.284 -0.240 -0.031
 0.568  0.367 -0.429  0.811 -0.007  0.786 -0.250  0.081  0.541
 0.125 -0.256 -0.492  0.839  0.079  0.665 -0.513 -0.422  0.039
```

[here](https://www.scribd.com/document/341976944/Method-1) are the computation instructions and examples

... I was wondering if this is just a standard approach in factor analysis or in pricipal component analysis.. and if so, which one? The introduction says that this method is rank reduction type solution in the sense that the major product of the factor score and factor loading matrices yields a residual which is precisely of rank equal to that of the original matrix less the number of factors.

This particular type of analysis is "direct" in the sense that is carried out directly on the raw data (at best it is the normalized matrix).